# EntityFramework select specific columns from lazy-loaded foreign key relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have three very simple tables joined together.  Two of the tables each have three columns, mainly integers.  The third has about 15 columns, mostly varchar.

The tables are like this:  `Spellbooks`, `Spells`, `SpellbookSpells`.  For each record in `Spellbooks`, there exist zero to many records in `SpellbookSpells`, which has a column for `Spellbook_Id` and `Spell_Id`.

So when I get `Spellbook book = db.Spellbooks.Find(id);`,

I get an object who has a `SpellbookSpells` property, which I can use to get a `List<Spell>` effectively.  That way when I return the data via JSON, it looks somewhat like this:

```
{
  "SpellbookSpells": [
    {
      "Spell": {
        "SpellbookSpells": [],
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Abi-Dalzim's Horrid Wilting",
        "Description": "<p>You draw the moisture from every creature in a 30-foot cube centered on a point you choose within range. Each creature in that area must make a Constitution saving throw. Constructs and undead aren't affected, and plants and water elementals make this saving throw with disadvantage. A creature takes 10d8 necrotic damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.You hurl a bubble of acid. Choose one creature within range, or choose two creatures within range that are within 5 feet of each other. A target must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or take 1d6 acid damage.</p><p>This spells damage increases by 1d6 when you reach 5th Level (2d6), 11th level (3d6) and 17th level (4d6).</p>",
        "Page": "ee pc 15",
        "Range": "150 feet",
        "Components": "V, S, M",
        "Ritual": false,
        "Duration": "Instantaneous",
        "Concentration": false,
        "CastingTime": "1 action",
        "Level": 8,
        "School": "Necromancy",
        "Classes": "Sorcerer, Wizard",
        "Archetype": null,
        "Domains": null,
        "Oaths": null,
        "Circles": null
      },
      "id": 1,
      "spellbook_id": 5,
      "spell_id": 1
    },
    {
      "Spell": {
        "SpellbookSpells": [],
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "Absorb Elements",
        "Description": "<p>The spell captures some of the incoming energy, lessening its effect on you and storing it for your next melee attack. You have resistance to the triggering damage type until the start of your next turn. Also, the first time you hit with a melee attack on your next turn, the target takes an extra 1d6 damage of the triggering type, and the spell ends.</p>",
        "Page": "ee pc 15",
        "Range": "Self",
        "Components": "S",
        "Ritual": false,
        "Duration": "1 round",
        "Concentration": false,
        "CastingTime": "1 action",
        "Level": 1,
        "School": "Abjuration",
        "Classes": "Druid, Ranger, Wizard",
        "Archetype": null,
        "Domains": null,
        "Oaths": null,
        "Circles": null
      },
      "id": 3,
      "spellbook_id": 5,
      "spell_id": 2
    },
    {
      "Spell": {
        "SpellbookSpells": [],
        "Id": 4,
        "Name": "Aganazzar's Scorcher",
        "Description": "<p>A line of roaring flame 30 feet long and 5 feet wide emanates from you in a direction you choose. Each creature in the line must make a Dexterity saving throw. A creature takes 3d8 fire damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.</p>",
        "Page": "ee pc 15",
        "Range": "30 feet",
        "Components": "V, S, M",
        "Ritual": false,
        "Duration": "Instantaneous",
        "Concentration": false,
        "CastingTime": "1 action",
        "Level": 2,
        "School": "Evocation",
        "Classes": "Sorcerer, Wizard",
        "Archetype": null,
        "Domains": null,
        "Oaths": null,
        "Circles": null
      },
      "id": 4,
      "spellbook_id": 5,
      "spell_id": 4
    },
    {
      "Spell": {
        "SpellbookSpells": [],
        "Id": 6,
        "Name": "Alarm",
        "Description": "<p>You set an alarm against unwanted intrusion. Choose a door, a window, or an area within range that is no larger than a 20-foot cube. Until the spell ends, an alarm alerts you whenever a Tiny or larger creature touches or enters the warded area. When you cast the spell, you can designate creatures that won’t set off the alarm. You also choose whether the alarm is mental or audible.</p><p>A mental alarm alerts you with a ping in your mind if you are within 1 mile of the warded area. This ping awakens you if you are sleeping.</p><p>An audible alarm produces the sound of a hand bell for 10 seconds within 60 feet.</p>",
        "Page": "phb 211",
        "Range": "30 feet",
        "Components": "V, S, M",
        "Ritual": true,
        "Duration": "8 hours",
        "Concentration": false,
        "CastingTime": "1 minute",
        "Level": 1,
        "School": "Abjuration",
        "Classes": "Ranger, Ritual Caster, Wizard",
        "Archetype": null,
        "Domains": null,
        "Oaths": null,
        "Circles": null
      },
      "id": 5,
      "spellbook_id": 5,
      "spell_id": 6
    }
  ],
  "Id": 5,
  "Name": "Krud",
  "UserId": "6922cf7c-6a86-4b7b-89d9-32ebbae43b8f"
}
```

However, the only properties of `Spell` that I want are `Id`,`Name`,`Level`, and `Classes`

How can I take `Spellbook book = db.Spellbooks.Find(id);` and only select specific columns of `Spells`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic query that produces the data you want is

```
var spellData = from sbs in db.SpellBookSpells
                where sbs.SpellBook_Id == id
                select new
                {
                    sbs.Id,
                    sbs.SpellBook_Id,
                    sbs.Spell_Id,
                    Spell = new
                    {
                        sbs.Spell_Id,
                        sbs.Spell.Name,
                        sbs.Spell.Level,
                        sbs.Spell.Classes
                    }
                };
```

Now it's up to you if you want to serialize this as anonymous types, or as DTOs or as the original entities.

If it's the first option, you're done. With DTOs you should add the DTO class names to the query:

```
var spellData = from sbs in db.SpellBookSpells
                where sbs.SpellBook_Id == id
                select new SpellBookSpellDto
                {
                    sbs.Id,
                    sbs.SpellBook_Id,
                    sbs.Spell_Id,
                    Spell = new SpellDto
                    {
                        sbs.Spell_Id,
                        sbs.Spell.Name,
                        sbs.Spell.Level,
                        sbs.Spell.Classes
                    }
                };
```

For obtaining original entities you should do

```
var spellDataEntities = from sbs in spellData.AsEnumerable()
                        select new SpellBookSpell
                        {
                            sbs.Id,
                            sbs.SpellBook_Id,
                            sbs.Spell_Id,
                            Spell = new Spell
                            {
                                sbs.Spell_Id,
                                sbs.Spell.Name,
                                sbs.Spell.Level,
                                sbs.Spell.Classes
                            }
                        };
```

The `AsEnumerable()` call is necessary because you can't create entity types in an EF LINQ query (the `IQueryable`) directly.

By using one of these options you load all required data in one query *and not one byte more*. By using `Find` you first load a `SpellBook` object that you don't really use anymore, after which you load its `SpellbookSpells` lazily. Even if you only select a limited number of properties from this collection, the complete entities are loaded first.

Comment: Wow!  This looks perfect.  Let me implement this over the next few minutes and then i'll accept this as the answer

Comment: Quick question though:  That's returning a bunch of spellbookspell records.  It's also returning the spellbook_id with every record, even though all those records are from the same spellbook.  is there any way I can optimize that a little more?  I'm specifically looking for spellbook's id, userid, and name, and then the list of spells associated with it.  Even if not, we're down from 900ms per request to about 180

Comment: You could wrap the whole structure in one object representing the `SpellBook`, similar to how a `Spell` is contained by a `SpellBookSpell`.

Comment: Great idea!  Thanks for the advice!  I'm totally new to using EF with multiple tables with relationships.  Usually I'm just hitting one table at a time.